# Jumplist in Windows 10 failing

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the below code to have the taskbar jumplist open the users default browser at certain pages.

Everything has been working fine for about a year now on Win 7/8 but with Windows 10 the browser is not called when the taskbar task is clicked and the Microsoft documentation shows no changes from Win 8 to 10.

```
 bool SetUpJumpList( )
 {
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<ICustomDestinationList> pDestList;
    hr = pDestList.CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_DestinationList , NULL , CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pDestList->SetAppID ( _TBID );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    UINT cMaxSlots;
    CComPtr<IObjectArray> pRemovedItems;
    hr = pDestList->BeginList ( &cMaxSlots , IID_PPV_ARGS ( &pRemovedItems ) );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    CComPtr<IObjectCollection> pObjColl;
    hr = pObjColl.CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_EnumerableObjectCollection , NULL , CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    if ( !AddJumpListTasks ( pObjColl ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    CComQIPtr<IObjectArray> pTasksArray = pObjColl;
    if ( !pTasksArray )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pDestList->AddUserTasks ( pTasksArray );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pDestList->CommitList( );
    return SUCCEEDED ( hr );
 }

 bool AddJumpListTasks ( IObjectCollection* pObjColl )
 {
    wchar_t pBuf[ MAX_PATH ];
    int bytes = GetModuleFileName ( NULL , pBuf , MAX_PATH );
    CJumpListTask aTasks[ ] =
    {
            { _T ( "https://www.google.co.uk" ) , _T ( "Home Page" ) , _T ( "Home" ) , 0 },
            { _T ( "https://www.google.co.uk" ) , _T ( "Twitter Page" ) , _T ( "Twitter" ) , 9 },
            { _T ( "https://www.google.co.uk" ) , _T ( "Facebook Page" ) , _T ( "Facebook" ) , 10 }
    };
    CString strBrowser;
    DWORD size = 1024;
    AssocQueryString ( 0 , ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE , L"http" , L"Open" , strBrowser.GetBufferSetLength ( size ) , &size );
    for ( int i = 0; i < _countof ( aTasks ); i++ )
    {
            if ( !AddJumpListTask ( pObjColl , aTasks[ i ] , strBrowser , pBuf ) )
            {
                    strBrowser.ReleaseBuffer( );
                    return false;
            }
    }
    strBrowser.ReleaseBuffer( );
    return true;
 }

 bool AddJumpListTask ( IObjectCollection* pObjColl , const CJumpListTask& rTask , LPCTSTR szExePath , LPCTSTR pBuf )
 {
    HRESULT hr;
    CComPtr<IShellLink> pLink;
    hr = pLink.CoCreateInstance ( CLSID_ShellLink , NULL , CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pLink->SetPath ( szExePath );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pLink->SetArguments ( rTask.szArgs );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pLink->SetIconLocation ( pBuf , rTask.nIconIndex );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    CComQIPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropStore = pLink;
    PROPVARIANT pv;
    if ( !pPropStore )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = InitPropVariantFromString ( CT2CW ( rTask.szTitle ) , &pv );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pPropStore->SetValue ( PKEY_Title , pv );
    PropVariantClear ( &pv );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pPropStore->Commit( );
    if ( FAILED ( hr ) )
    {
            return false;
    }
    hr = pObjColl->AddObject ( pLink );
    return SUCCEEDED ( hr );
 }
```

I've noticed several other applications such as CCleaner that also use this method do not function either but Microsoft applications such as Office 2013 still work so the question is how do I get this running again on Windows 10?

I'm certain this is not related to the ***customDestinations-ms*** files stored in the CustomDestinations folder as with a clean install of Windows 10 the same non functionality appears.

The taskbar task menu is created with the desired text and icon and debugging shows the correct URL is added along with the correct default browser and browser path.

**Edit:**

Using Visual Studio 2015 with toolset Windows XP v140_xp

Comment: Can you try ".html" or ".htm" instead of "http" in the call to AssocQueryString. The `AssocQueryString` says it takes an extension.

Comment: What does your debugging tell you about the point of failure

Comment: Tried both ".html" and ".htm" "http"/"https" does work on Windows 7/8/8.1.

Comment: My debugging is telling me everything is fine but I'm not exactly sure how I debug the taskbar tasks being clicked as that is handled by the operating system.

Comment: What are the values of the arguments passed to AddJumpListTas?

Comment: I've just checked that and everything going to AddJumpListTask is what it should be, updated the question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could use, if possible for you, the MFC Class "CJumplist" from the latest Windows SDK.

We found out it would fix this issue, but only if using the latest SDK version. Using an older SDK using the same MFC class (eg Windows 7 SDK) would cause exactly the same issues you are experiencing.

This is a sample code working on Windows 10 with VC2013 and latest SDK (Target v12.0), but only when using MFC in a shared Dll. Linking with a static MFC Dll does not seem to work.

```
CJumpList *pJumpList = new CJumpList();
pJumpList->SetAppID(m_pszAppID);
result = pJumpList->AddTask(szPath, _T("-data1"), _T("number 4"), szPath, 0);
result = pJumpList->AddTask(szPath, _T("-data2"), _T("number 5"), szPath, 0);
pJumpList->CommitList();
delete pJumpList;
```

I do not know what changes Microsoft developers have done in this class to make it work. Our pure Win32 code suffers the same issues as you reported.

Answer (score 0):

A little update to this, a reinstall of Windows due to other issues followed by a reinstall of VS but not checking the XP compatibility options results in the Jumplists working again, I dont need XP support anyhow but I assume this issue is related to the XP library's.